# Script# and Google maps

Tags: c#, google-maps, script#

Has anyone found how to integrate Google Maps and Script#?

I'm trying to tie the two together, most of the research ends in this [GMapsSharp Project](https://gmapsharp.codeplex.com/). However that project was compiled against an older version of Script#(0.7.0) which makes unusable with the current version(0.7.5).

I'm open to suggestions, if anyone knows a GMaps wrapper, a way of wrapping it, or how to fix the compatibility issues between GMapsharp and Scriptsharp that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: Don't do it.

I was going to build that, but started to use OpenLayers which is a much better library overall. However, when I started with OL, they were already working on version 3 but we had to use 2 as 3 wasn't ready so it didn't make sense to stub it. OpenLayers 3 is very close to releasing now so it makes sense to strub it.

I'm working on the integrating now. However, the library is vast and stubbing it is not trivial. I'm stubbing only pieces that I'm using at the moment. Hence, I'm not contributing it back to S# yet. If you're interested in contributing, I can do this on my fork and then eventually merge it into main.